# How to use a user defined function in SQL that is from another db

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a user defined function in a different database than the one i am querying from. Is there a way to access the function such as a fully qualified name or something similar in SQL?
I am trying to do this

```
[dbo].[EscalationManagementSystem].fncCVUnix2DateTZ(...
```

But i get an error saying that it cannot find the column "dbo" or the user defined function "dbo.EscalationManagemntSystem.fncCVUnix2DateTZ". Is my syntax wrong?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The proper format is Database.Schema.Object, so you would have:

`[EscalationManagementSystem].[dbo].[fncCVUnix2DateTZ](...`

Answer (score 3):

Every time you need to access objects from another db you should use something called the "four part name convention" which is:

> SERVER.DATABASE.SCHEMA.OBJECT

Comment: You only need the server name if going to a different server than what the current database is located on; that is the only time you should specify the server name.